# How to know the app suspension reason in WinRT app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, suspend

In my Universal app, (Windows 8.1 Windows Phone8.1), I want to know the reason why my app is suspended like due to a launch of a launcher(Mail, File picker etc) or user pressed the Windows button. Is there a way to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't know what caused the app's suspension. Unlike the [LaunchActivatedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.aspx) in the `OnLaunched` method for example, that contain the `Kind` property the [SuspendingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.suspendingeventargs.aspx) in the `OnSuspending` method don't provide any such information.

However, there are only so many reasons that an app can be suspended. Like you said (in windows phone only) it can be suspended due to a launch of a launcher or a protocol and by the windows button.

The windows button is the only suspension way of which you have no control. For all the others you can trick the system and for example set a static global variable that you update when you launch an operation that would suspend your app and check it in `OnSuspending`